# Numpy array length (number of rows) will not exceed 99,999

Tags: python, numpy, csv

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import numpy as np

array_rows = 364320

rates = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos(i, time_frame, 0, array_rows)
modified_rates = np.insert(arr=rates, obj=0, values=int(0), axis=0)
print(modified_array)
```

The code above is used to generate the OHLCV market data array below (excerpt) and write it to a csv file.

```
[(         0, 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     ,  0,  0, 0)
 (1631077200, 1.18471, 1.18474, 1.18469, 1.18472, 13, 12, 0)
 (1631077260, 1.1847 , 1.18475, 1.18469, 1.18474,  9, 12, 0) 
 (1639598520, 1.12593, 1.12604, 1.12593, 1.126  , 27, 10, 0)
 ....... )]
```

The problem is that the number of array rows will not exceed 99,999 - How can this be resolved?

Comment: what do you mean? Are you getting an error of some sort? Running out of memory maybe?

Comment: there's no error message!

Comment: if its memory, wouldn't the number of rows terminate at an arbitrary number and not consistently at 99,999?

Comment: the array takes up under 63MB (using the code - import os, psutil; print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))

Comment: the array uses up under 63MB and there is 3,153MB of memory available

Comment: Specs are:
- Processor: 2.50 GHz
- RAM: 8.00 GB
- System: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: So if there is no error, how do you know it's not exceeding 99,999 rows? Are you printing the length of the array, looking at it in a debugger or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 99999 is the maximum number of bars stored in the MT5 history database.

Comment: Thank you Andres G - i'll pick it up with the broker.

Comment: I expanded the maximum number of bars by changing the settings in my MT5 client